# iOS iPhone 11 Xcode simulator keyboard (hard and soft) returning incorrect string

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, simulator

With this code

```
- (IBAction)textFieldChange:(id)sender {
    NSString* theText = [sender text];
    NSLog( @"textFieldChange: theText '%@'", theText);
```

I enter "5[blank][blank]" and upon entering the second blank theText becomes "5.[blank]".  Yes, the first blank changes to a period.  Doesn't happen with the real iPhone 11.  Any ideas?  Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262).

```
    2021-05-14 15:31:10.304996-0700 M[55352:1497186] textFieldChange: theText '5'
    2021-05-14 15:31:10.609588-0700 M[55352:1497186] textFieldChange: theText '5 '
    2021-05-14 15:31:11.049957-0700 M[55352:1497186] textFieldChange: theText '5. '
```

Comment: I've seen other examples of such errors, but this one is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of two consecutive spaces depends on the `"." Shortcut` setting in the device keyboard settings.

[image]

It sounds like this is turned on on your simulators but off on your iPhone